# One App Delegate, Two Windows

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a simple Cocoa app. It has two windows, each in a separate xib file:

- MainMenu.xib
- SecondaryWindow.xib

I have an AppDelegate class, which has a reference to the window in MainMenu.xib. I'm trying to make it have a reference to the window in SecondaryWindow.xib. I'm confused about how to do this. I have made an outlet, as such:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *secondaryWindow;

@end
```

Here's the implementation:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize secondaryWindow = _secondaryWindow;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SecondaryWindow" owner:self];
    NSLog(@"_window = %@", _window);
    NSLog(@"_secondaryWindow = %@", _secondaryWindow);
}

@end
```

_secondaryWindow is always (null)

I've add an outlet from in SecondaryWindow.xib connection the second window to the outlet in AppDelegate. What else do I need to do in SecondaryWindow.xib to make the connection complete?

EDIT: added [NSBundle loadNibNamed...]

Answer (score 1):

You need to load it...
By default, MainWindow.xib is loaded by the framework, which creates its own instance of the app delegate.
You should load your second window from your app delegate (try `[NSBundle  laodNibNamed:@"SecondaryWindow" owner:self]`. when you do this, the File's owner will be the application delegate - change the class of the file's owner in interface builder to reflect that and make your connections to it)

Comment: thanks martin. I added [NSBundle loadNibNamed..], as it was the closest I could find in the docs to your suggestion. I've revised my question to show this. But still, secondaryWindow is null... Am I using the wrong owner in loadNibNamed? Or perhaps applicationDidFinishLaunching is not the right method?

Comment: Hi Martin, I still can't find [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed...] is that perhaps for iOS and not for OS X?

Comment: i meant those.. mixed it up ^^: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the type of File's Owner in the secondary window's .xib to the type of your app delegate? And did you then connect the window in that .xib to the `secondaryWindow` outlet of File's Owner?

If you did those things, and if the .xib is properly included in the project and you've specified the name of the file correctly in the `+loadNibNamed:owner:` message, then your `secondaryWindow` property should be populated.